# How to send email at once for selected list of email addresses having more than one in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

This is my code for sending emails to only one email address. As I'm sending birthday wishes to customers from my project I need send it all together not as selecting one by one. The below code sends emails to customers successfully when there is only one birthday event. Please help me to change this code to do so.

```
function getEmail()
    {       
        $query = $this->db->query("select ci.* from customer_info ci where month(b_day) = month(curdate()) and day(b_day) = day(curdate());");
        $data = $query->row_array();
        $value = $data['email'];
        return $value;
    }

public function sendMailToComplete($ID)
    {
        $email = $this->getEmail();
        foreach ($this->get_db->getEmailConfig() as $row) {
            $config = Array(
                            'protocol' => $row->protocol,
                            'smtp_host' => $row->host,
                            'smtp_user' => $row->user,
                            'smtp_pass' => $row->pass,
                            'smtp_port' => $row->port,
                            'smtp_timeout'=>$row->timeout,
                            'mailtype'  => $row->mailtype, 
                            'charset'   => $row->charset
                            );
            $this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from($row->from, 'ABC');
            $this->email->to($email);
            $this->email->subject('Birthday Greetings');
            $this->email->message('Many Happy Returns Of The Day!!! Have A Wonderful Birthday... .');
        }

       $this->email->send();
    }
```

Comment: you have to send in comma `,` separated values.

Comment: it should have to recieve as an array right?

Comment: are you using codeigniter??

Comment: yes I am using cordeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you use `CodeIgniter`

First, it's a realy bad idea to send birthday greetings to the multiple recepients at once(in `to` header of one email) because it's privacy-less - **all recepients will see email addresses of each other.**

As i understood the prbolem is that your `getEmail` function returns `email` only for one(first in sql resultset) customer, but you need to send greetings to all customers.

So you should fetch not one, but all birthday boys and then iterate over them.

**1** First replace your `getEmail` function to the `getBirthdayBoys` one which will return an array of customers.

```
function getBirthdayBoys()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("select ci.* from customer_info ci where month(b_day) = month(curdate()) and day(b_day) = day(curdate());");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**2** And then use updated function within your mail sending function like this:

```
public function sendMailToComplete($ID)
{
    $customers = $this->getBirthdayBoys();
    if (empty($customers)) {
        return;
    }

    $config = array(
        'protocol' => $row->protocol,
        'smtp_host' => $row->host,
        'smtp_user' => $row->user,
        'smtp_pass' => $row->pass,
        'smtp_port' => $row->port,
        'smtp_timeout'=>$row->timeout,
        'mailtype'  => $row->mailtype,
        'charset'   => $row->charset

    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);

    foreach ($customers as $customer)
    {
        $email = $customer['email'];
        $this->email->clear();  
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from($row->from, 'ABC');
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('Birthday Greetings');
        $this->email->message('Many Happy Returns Of The Day!!! Have A Wonderful Birthday... .');
        $this->email->send();
    }

    $this->email->clear();
}
```

**Attention**:
But you still have a few problems with your `sendMailToComplete($ID)` function.

1. `$row` is undefined variable.
2. `$ID` argument never used

Comment: Oh thank you soo much.. This is perfectly working...Thank you for pointing out my errors as well..Btw I used that $ID for further references as I thought I might need it.. But it's a mistake I don't need it anymore. And secondly the $row is a defined variable in my above posted code... Thank you soo much for your help..I'm really greatfull..

Comment: @Akisha you are not sending email at once, you are sending one by one in forloop. not good idea.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju why do you think so?
sending of single mail to multiple persons at once has following cons:
1. privacy violation - recepients email addresses will be revealed to each other 2. text of single email should be general in nature, and can't be personalized with a person's name

Comment: @PavelSadchenko My review is based on the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass an array to `email->to`. But it should be a comma `,` separated values like this.

```
$this->email->to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com');
```

For more reference check [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html)

To send email at once,

```
 implode(",",$emailarray);
```

else

```
concat() in your query.
```

Comment: sure, let me know about the result.

Comment: Oh yes it is working.. It sends to email adresses I included.. Just a one question if u can help..Help me to take this to an array

Comment: `use implode(",",$email);` or use `concat()` in your query.

Comment: @Akisha Did u got the required behaviour??

Comment: Yes.. I got this as I wanted.. As you said it is iterating through a for loop and as I noticed it takes some time to send those emails..But as Pavel Sadchenko mentioned it is not displaying customers email adresses to all.. So in terms of privacy I think it's most preferred..Thank you soo much for the help... :)